# python code for writing sensor data to a text file in decimal format

Tags: python

I am using a VB-8200 vibration meter for my project. It gives vibration measure in a 16 digit format. Eg. 000001????0004. This means vibration value is 0.4 mm/s. I want to write a python code for sending 0.4 to a text file after recieving it.
The code I have written is given below:

```
import string
    import time
    import serial
     ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS3', baudrate=9600,                                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=0.0005)try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print("serial port is open")
    except:
    print("error")
    exit()
    if(ser.isOpen()):
    try:
        while(1):
        x=ser.readline().rstrip('\0')
        print x
        y= x[11:]
        textdata = str(y)/10
        f = open('/home/root/sensor_data.txt','a')
        f.write(textdata+'\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        f.close()
    except Exception:
    print("error")
    else:
    print("cannot open serial terminal")
```

However it is not working. Can you help me in correcting this. When I am not doing /10 in, textdata = str(y)/10, it is working. But i need to send the data in integer format to text file, so that i can plot it in thingspeak.

Comment: Please clarify the question.  what does this mean `000001????0004`? .What is the problem, explain the last two sentences

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
textdata = str(y)/10
```

you are attempting to divide a string by 10, which doesn't make sense.  Since y is already a string (you obtained it above by stripping the first 11 characters from x), you first want to convert it to an integer:

```
iy = int(y)
```

That function will handle leading zeros for you.

You know that iy is the flow rate in units of 0.1mm/s.  To get the flow rate in real units, you do:

```
flow_rate = iy * 0.1
```

To write integers to the file, just do:

```
f.write(str(iy) + '\n')
```

It won't have any leading zeros.